# Encountered error while updating pages in a database with Notion API

Tags: javascript, notion-api

I recently made an integration between Todoist and Notion. The main idea is that every time I do something with a task on Todoist, the changes are reflected on Notion. I'm encountering a problem with the `notion.pages.update()` function: every time I modify a task, it returns this error:
`body failed validation. Fix one: body.properties.body.id should be defined, instead was undefined. body.properties.body.name should be defined, instead was undefined. body.properties.body.start should be defined, instead was undefined.`
I don't even have a `body` property in my database.

Here's my update function, keep in mind that this is a function inside a module I made:

```js
my.updateTask = async function (notion_page_id, name, todoist_project_id, do_date, priority, in_discord) {
  var req_body = {
    page_id: notion_page_id,
    properties: {
      Name: {
        type: "title",
        title: [
          {
            type: "rich_text",
            rich_text: {
              content: name
            }
          }
        ],
      },
      Project: {
        type: "relation",
        relation: [
          {
            database_id: my.getProject("todoist_id", todoist_project_id).notion_id
          }
        ]
      },
      Priority: {
        number: priority
      },
      isOnDiscord: {
        checkbox: in_discord
      }
    }
  }
  if (typeof do_date !== 'undefined' && do_date !== null) {
    start_dt = new Date(do_date.date);
    end_dt = new Date(do_date.date);
    end_dt.setHours(end_dt.getHours() + 24);
    req_body.properties.DoDate = {
      date: {
        start: start_dt.toISOString().replace(/Z$/, '+02:00'),
        end: end_dt.toISOString().replace(/Z$/, '+02:00')
      }
    }
  }
  const response = await my.api.pages.update(req_body);
  return response !== {};
}
```

Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I think your Name property should look like this:

```
Name: {
    title: [
        {
            text: { content: name }
        }
    ]
}
```

You can see that here in the docs: https://developers.notion.com/reference/patch-page

Comment: i already changed it to rich text bc it was giving me even more errors...

Answer (score -1):

I solved it, the problem was actually in another function (the `getProject` function)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).